# swift plist decoder global Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, plist

I want a dictionary out of my plist, which i can use in the whole gamescene. However in my solution i always have to call the parseConfig function in order to get a dictionary from the plist.

```
struct Config: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case zPositions, enemy, player
    }

    let zPositions: [String:Double]
    let enemy: [String:[String:Double]]
    let player: [String:[String:Double]]
}

func parseConfig() -> Config {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Config", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    return try! decoder.decode(Config.self, from: data)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try crate lazy property.

Something like: - if use gloabaly

```
var parsedConfig: Config  = {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Config", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    return try! decoder.decode(Config.self, from: data)
}()
```

if in class add lazy before var

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write a closure to load only once

```
lazy var myConfig : Config  = {  
      let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Config", withExtension: "plist")!
      let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
      let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
      return try! decoder.decode(Config.self, from: data)
}()
```

or inside a singleton in all the app

```
class Service {

 static let shared = Service()

  lazy var myConfig : Config  = { 

      let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Config", withExtension: "plist")!
      let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
      let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
      return try! decoder.decode(Config.self, from: data)
  }()

}
```